# SQL Help: Partition By Clause (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, partition-by

I don't have much experience with using Partition By Clauses, and I'm having trouble coming up with a working query for the below data, despite digging around all of the usual places.

Please refer to the attachment link, but suffice to say I am looking for "top 3" [Companies] (highest [Amount Due]) for each [Rep].  Data has been simplified, please let me know if you have any questions or suggestions!

[image: Example Input / Expected Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by rep order by amount_due desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, tested and verified this does exactly what I was looking for.